# Android Contacts form

Tags: android, iphone, contacts

Is there a possibility in Android to implement a **Contacts form** like it's realised on the iPhone?

So, i mean, is there a **default Android Contacts-Site in the framework** that can be used? 
It doesn't have to look like on the iPhone.

[image]

I want to start this Activity with **Extras**(i.putExtra) which contain the Contact Data, so that the Contact that's selected in the previous Activity will be shown in these fields. After this, there should be the possibility to **add** all this information **to the Contacts**.

Comment: are you talking about making it _behave_ like the iphone contacts form or making it _look_ like it? You should clarify your question.

Comment: I want to make it _behave_ like the iPhone contacts. It doesn't have to look like. So I want to know if there's a default Android Contacts-Site in the framework. I edited my question, thank you for you note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow the user to select a contact using this..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

**2) Calling the Contact Picker**

Within your Activity, create an Intent that asks the system to find an Activity that can perform a PICK action from the items in the Contacts URI.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

Call startActivityForResult, passing in this Intent (and a request code integer, PICK_CONTACT in this example). This will cause Android to launch an Activity that's registered to support ACTION_PICK on the People.CONTENT_URI, then return to this Activity when the selection is made (or canceled).

```
 startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

switch (reqCode) {
case (PICK_CONTACT) :
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
 Uri contactData = data.getData();
 Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
 if (c.moveToFirst()) 
 {
   String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));

 }
}
break;
}
}
```

Now once a contact is selected you will have the information you need to fill in your edittexts and all above.

This is en excellent tutorial on how to do this. Good Luck! This should get you well on your way!
[Working with Androind contacts](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/)

Comment: Thanks, but I think that I couldn't make it clear what I want. When I follow your instructions, I get this: [PICTURE](http://www.xup.in/dl,96926745/getContact.jpg/) But I want just to send some data - that I don't have in my contacts on the phone but in the type of **strings in another activity** - into something like an **Contact-Edit/Add-Activity**. Right now I think that I have to create a own Activity with EditTexts, arranged as a form. Or is there another solution?

Comment: that sounds about right. Create a layout in the way of a form, and then allow the user to edit the text in the fields, and maybe have a send button, that will do whatever you want with the information the user entered.